# Programmatic way to manage cookies in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I don't like how I am tracked by Facebook. To delete Facebook cookies from the Chrome browser, I need at least seven mouse clicks. Is there a way to write a script to delete all cookies, local storage, session variables, database storage, etc in Chrome from all sites with name containing `*facebook*`?

Comment: By the way, you cannot delete data from their databases, but you may be able to create a plugin that does this for you.

Comment: I was refering to the browser's database.  Perhaps it's the same as local storage, but in Chrome settings I see Indexed Database.

Comment: Oh, then yeas. I probably is. Sorry I don't have much experience in that.

Comment: @OldGeezer It's easy enough to use incognito mode (`Ctrl+Shift+N`), which deletes cookies when you close the window.  There also might be a plugin which blacklists cookies from a certain site. (Just make sure you don't blacklist the session cookie, or you won't be able to log in; you can find it by process of elimination, of course.)